# Pass JavaScript Value to PHP or another PHP class (codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having a dilemma on how to pass a JS variable value to my model.php where my query resides. To make it short. here's my code:

in the PHP file under views, I have RP_Report.php in the HTML body resides:

```
<p>From Date: <input type="text" id="fromdate">   
From Date: <input type="text" id="todate">   </br></br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">GENERATE</button> </br>
<p id="body">
```

in the same file's HTML header:

```
function myFunction(){
//document.getElementById("body").innerHTML=d ocument.getElementById("fromdate").value;
var fromDate = document.getElementById("fromdate").value;
var ToDate = document.getElementById("todate").value;
}
```

So the button calls the JS block up top to get the value of the datepicker fields.

What I wanted to happen is to get `var fromDate` and `var ToDate` and use it in the query inside Models db_model.php for the whereclause

```
public function rp_total_attempts_stmt()
{
    $stmt = $this->db->query("SELECT phone_number,
        DATE(LEFT(CAST(call_date AS CHAR),LENGTH(CAST(call_date AS CHAR)) - 9)) AS call_date,
        COUNT(*) AS total_call_attempts  FROM vicidial_log 
        WHERE (SELECT lead_id FROM vicidial_list WHERE vicidial_log.lead_id = vicidial_list.`lead_id`)
        GROUP BY phone_number ORDER BY call_date desc");
    return $stmt->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: use ajax to pass value

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Ajax in order to communicate between your client (JavaScript) and your server (PhP). Ajax is based on the XmlHttpRequest object and offers the possibility to send and receive data to/from a server without refreshing the page.

It can carry several types of data such as XML but also HTML, raw text, or JSON. To send data to your server in your case you just need to call your PhP page with a parameter in the GET/POST method.

See here for more info : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/